# React Navigation - Custom Header Animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation inside React Native App and i created a Custom Header Component for my routes

like this :

```js
const Router = StackNavigator({
 Main: {
     screen: Main,
     navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
         header:<Header title="Main"/>
     })
   },
})
```

when using a custom header component the native animation not working
i would like to know how can i achieve the animation in the header the same as here https://reactnavigation.org/

Answer (score 5):

**TL:DR;** found solution to share the animated.Value / interpolation over screens code below.

[Animated Custom Header React-native + React navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvD64.jpg)

This post was taunting me for some time - I was faced with the same issue. Hopefully this will reach you even if it's couple of months later :D

So first my issue was this, I made a component for custom header like in your example, my target was having one of the StackNavigator pages, have a scrollView which would in turn manipulate the color of the header.

Similar issue, the information exchange between header and page should help you too, here it goes.

**Header.js**

```js
export class HeaderBar extends Component {
componentWillMount(){
    // might be a bit, ehm but worked so if you have tips how to make the code nice feel free to share 
    let valueToManipulate= new Animated.Value(0);
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        valueToManipulate,
        customkey: valueToManipulate.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 150],
            outputRange: ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
        })
    })
}

render () {   

    ... bit of code ...
    // important bit for data binding ! 
    if( ! (this.props.navigation.state.params &&  this.props.navigation.state.params.customkey) ){
        return null;
    }
    /* unless that variable on params exists we do not ! render */ 

    ... bit more of code ... 

    <View style={ floating }>
            <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor: this.props.navigation.state.params.customkey  }}> /// <<--- typical bind 
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between"}}>

     ... and rest of render ...
```

So this is the header bit, now for the other "fun" part:

**HomePage.js**

```js
export default class HomePage extends Component<{}> {

     ... stufff..... :D 

     render() {

     /* this here, again data binding !, do not let render before we have this var in state params ! */ 
     if( !( this.props.navigation.state.params && this.props.navigation.state.params.valueToManipulate ) )
          return null;

     return (

        <ScrollView
            style={styles.container}
            onScroll={ Animated.event(
                [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.props.navigation.state.params.valueToManipulate } } }], // <-- tadaaa
            )}
            bounces={false}
            scrollEventThrottle={1}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
      ... moar stuff ... 
    } 
}
```

And here ! Finally ! A Demo !
[Animated Custom Header React-native + React navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvD64.jpg)

Comment: Confirm work. But remember to use useNativeDriver to improve performance.